# Remove files that should not have been commited

Tags: git, version-control

I have a .gitignore file in my project directory and I placed the following entry in the file to not to commit the files in the following folder:

```
EStudyMongoDb.Integration.Test\
```

For some reason Git pushed the files to repository anyway!

Anyway! now I want to remove those files that have been pushed to the repository but I don't want to loose my local changes to the files inside the folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the \ with / or remove it completely.
Use git rm --cached EStudyMongoDb.Integration.Test to remove it from the index

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`git rm --cached`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) to remove the files from the index but *not* from your working copy. Then, commit the changes.